# Is it possible to have 2 different type of authentication for the same entrypoint in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I know in Spring security it is possible to have two different authentication for different endpoints using Order for several Adapters (   [example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-entry-points) ) My question will be , is it possible to have different type of authentication for the same entry point differentiated via HttpHeader parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide multiple WebSecurityConfigurerAdapters and use request matcher to match requests containing specific headers like--

1. http.requestMatcher(new
   RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("user-form-login")).formLogin().....
2. http.requestMatcher(new
   RequestHeaderRequestMatcher("user-http-basic")).httpBasic() ...